# rewrite query in orden to avoid some records

Tags: sql

I dont know how to rewrite the the query in order to avoid records with ISPRIMARY = 0. In other words the values allowed must be ISPRIMARY = 1 and ISPRIMARY = NULL.

The query is the next:

```
select 
  S.assetnum, S.description, S.serialnum,
  S.epp_codactfij, S.location, L.description,
  S.EPP_NUMCONTRATO, S.PURCHASEPRICE, U.personid, U.isprimary
from maximo.asset S 
left join maximo.locations L on S.location=L.location
left join maximo.assetusercust U on S.assetnum=U.assetnum
where 
S.siteid ='TI'
order by S.assetnum
```

Comment: It works!!! thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following line to the `WHERE` clause:

```
select 
S.assetnum, S.description, S.serialnum, S.epp_codactfij, S.location, L.description, S.EPP_NUMCONTRATO, S.PURCHASEPRICE, U.personid, U.isprimary
from maximo.asset S 
left join maximo.locations L on S.location=L.location
left join maximo.assetusercust U on S.assetnum=U.assetnum
where 
S.siteid ='TI'
-- add this line
AND (U.isprimary = 1 OR U.isprimary IS NULL)
order by S.assetnum
```

Comment: May I ask why you add answer that are the same as already posted?

Comment: My view of this page sees this as the earliest answer, by 1 minute.

Comment: It was really close. Sorry if I stepped on someone's toes there.

Comment: @DanBracuk Maybe we have different SO then.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  S.assetnum, S.description, S.serialnum, S.epp_codactfij,
  S.location, L.description, S.EPP_NUMCONTRATO,
  S.PURCHASEPRICE, U.personid, U.isprimary
from maximo.asset S 
left join maximo.locations L on S.location=L.location
left join maximo.assetusercust U on S.assetnum=U.assetnum
WHERE S.siteid ='TI' AND (U.isprimary = 1 OR U.isprimary IS NULL)
order by S.assetnum;
```

or:

```
select 
  S.assetnum, S.description, S.serialnum, S.epp_codactfij,
  S.location, L.description, S.EPP_NUMCONTRATO,
  S.PURCHASEPRICE, U.personid, U.isprimary
from maximo.asset S 
left join maximo.locations L on S.location=L.location
left join maximo.assetusercust U on S.assetnum=U.assetnum
WHERE S.siteid ='TI' AND (U.isprimary <> 0 OR U.isprimary IS NULL)
order by S.assetnum;
```